# ActiveRecord query to sum over joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to get the sum of the receipt items that are in a particular budget (same title) and from the current query I'm getting to many record and obvious wrong sum of amounts from the receipt items.

My current attempt is looking like that in ActiveRecord (AR):

```
ReceiptItem.includes(donation: [:budgets]).joins(:donation, :receipt).where(budgets: {title: "Some title 2015"}).sum(:amount)
```

and my SQL attempt was looking like that (its also wrong):

```
-- want to test just the outcome its not actually not summing up the amounts
SELECT "receipt_items"."amount"
FROM
  "receipt_items" INNER JOIN "donations" ON "donations"."id" = "receipt_items"."donation_id"
    RIGHT JOIN "receipts" ON "receipts"."receipt_id" = "receipt_items"."receipt_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "budgets" ON "budgets"."donation_id" = "donations"."id"
WHERE "budgets"."title" = 'Some title 2015';
```

#### Why I'm getting double records although I've joined the tables and set also the condition?

Here is the ER modell to understand the problem.
[image: ER model]

And here's the AR Assoziations:

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donation
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :receipt_items
    has_many :budgets
class ReceiptItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donation
```

Comment: Can you add your associations to your question, and spell out a bit more exactly what you're trying to get?

Comment: @MaxWilliams sorry forgot to add that :)

Comment: so one row in `recept_items` can have several `recept_id` ?..

Comment: change to `SELECT "receipt_items"."amount","receipts"."receipt_id"
FROM
  "receipt_items" INNER JOIN "donations" ON "donations"."id" = "receipt_items"."donation_id"
    RIGHT JOIN "receipts" ON "receipts"."receipt_id" = "receipt_items"."receipt_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "budgets" ON "budgets"."donation_id" = "donations"."id"
WHERE "budgets"."title" = 'Some title 2015';` does it show you several recepts?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a budget can be linked to a reciept item multiple times, via different donations, it's appearing in the big join table multiple times, and thus being counted several times.

Let's try to think this through a step at a time.  If you wanted to do it without worrying about eager loading, you would do:

```
Budget.where(title: "some title").all.collect(&:donation).collect(&:receipt_items).flatten.uniq.collect(&:amount).sum
```

is that right?

If so, you can tailor the eager loading to fit this chain of method calls:

```
Budget.where(title: "some title", include: {:donation => [:receipt_items]}).all.collect(&:donation).collect(&:receipt_items).uniq.collect(&:amount).sum
```

try that?

Comment: Yeahh! The first solution was working perfectly fine. I've used the eager loading with the first solution `Budget.includes(donation:[:receipt_items]).where(title: "Some title 2015").all.collect(&:donation).collect(&:receipt_items).flatten.uniq.collect(&:amount).sum`

Comment: The 2nd one had some issues with the include and was also not delivering the right result.

Comment: You should be able to tweak the second one to get it to do the query more efficiently.  But, the most important thing is always that it works.

Comment: Ohhhh I've got wrong value! I have create on Budget with the title `2015` and another `2016` based on the same `donation`. Beside that I have create just one ReceiptItem.

Comment: I have added a condition to check also on Daten `Budget.includes(donation:[:receipt_items]).where(title: budget_title, start_date: same_budgets.first.start_date, end_date: same_budgets.first.end_date).all.collect(&:donation).collect(&:receipt_items).flatten.uniq.collect(&:amount).sum` But it doesn't helped

Comment: Sounds to me like it's time for a new question.